# How to generate float sequence in Presto?

Tags: sql, sequence, presto, amazon-athena

I want to generate float range which can be unnested into a column in PrestoDb. I am following documentation https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html and trying out 'sequence' but looks like float ranges cannot be generated in sequence. I want to generate a table like below with the value interval reduced by 0.3

```
| date       | value |
| 2020-01-31 |  47.6 |
| 2020-02-28 |  47.3 |
| 2020-03-31 |  47.0 |
```

I was trying to generate a sequence and then unnest it into column values. I am able to generate date column using the sequence in prestodb but not the value column

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sequence`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) with `bigint` and convert to `double` after unnesting:

```
presto> SELECT x / 10e0 FROM UNNEST(sequence(476, 470, -3)) t(x);
 _col0
-------
  47.6
  47.3
  47.0
```

(verified on Presto 336)

Comment: any workaround for sequence limitation ? "result of sequence function must not have more than 10000 entries"

Comment: @WAnjum This is a safely limitation to prevent user queries from creating humongous arrays. Perhaps this could be avoided by introducing a dedicated block representation. I recommend you file a new issue https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/new.

Comment: @WAnjum Also, you can get your case consulted on the `#troubleshooting` channel on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html) -- usually the limitation can be worked around, on a case by case basis.